# Automated testing with Smart Card authentication (selenium or other option?)

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, smartcard

We host hundreds of websites with smart card authentication (CAC authentication for those with DoD experience).  I need to build automated tests for these sites. In regular industry, I have used Selenium for end-to-end testing suites, but these websites I must test require smart card authentication.

When a user visits a site, the browser pops-up a window asking which certificate from the smart card to use.  This pop-up will prevent me from automating clicks within the DOM, right?  Is there a best practice to get around it?

Comment: It depends on the browser. With Chrome it's possible to auto-select a certificate for a given url by setting the preferences.

Comment: @davidhaskins Did you ever get this to work? I'd love to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the recent releases of each Selenium Client handling of pop-ups have become much easier. Using Selenium, you can deal easily with the following kinds of pop-ups:

- **`Basic Authentication popup`** (Windows)
- **`Modal popup`** (HTML DOM )
- **`Alert`** (JavaScript)

As far as **Certificates** are concerned we can easily handle them through separate `Profiles`.